# Asp.net error Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After a computer crash my Visual Studio 2010 will not load an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975455/after-a-computer-crash-my-visual-studio-2010-will-not-load-an-assembly)

I have a web application in Asp.net MVC 3 developed in VS 2010. Today while working my laptop got rebooted due to some reason and from that time onward when I run my app from VS it gives me error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.AspNet4' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

On googling I found few solutions

1. Clean asp.net temp files
2. Reinstall .net framework

I tried first solution but it didn't work. Before I try second solution I would like to know if there is any other alternative to fix this problem?

Comment: You can try right-clicking on the Solution and choose "Clean Solution", then "Rebuild Solution".

Comment: Here is the solution which worked for me. [link](http://rpelepei.blogspot.com/2010/11/hresult-0x80070057-einvalidarg.html)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Delete all files from the following folders and try again:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```

Comment: Yep, a computer crash for me too.  Thanks!   (Visual Studio 2012 / MVC 4 for me ) and not just EF.

Comment: It also reproduces on Windows Server 2012 + IIS 8