# Warning ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing using ASP.NET in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. Everything works great but suddenly when changing some code in one of my controllers Visual Studio crashed and now I got this weird runtime error:

**Warning   1 \Views_Create.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))**

My project still works fine though only a bit slower than before but every aspect of code, views, models, controller works just fine. Only in my studio the lines using EF are being underlined and marked as warning which is kinda annoying!

I already tried to uninstall and install EF or upgrade to EF 6.1 but no results...

Anybody an idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer posted in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641337/asp-net-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) solved the problem for me:

```
Delete all files from the following folders and try again:

C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```