# ASP.NET type for older version of EntityFramework not resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My ASP.NET MVC 5 EF 6 Application crashed because "System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0" was not found. I was wondering about the version 6.0 because I'm using the latest version 6.1.3.0 but I couldn't found any references to 6.0.0.0 which may cause this problem.

The solution to [delete all temp ASP.NET files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27838364/3276634) had no effect. Using NuGet, I downgraded the EntityFramework package from 6.1.3.0 to 6.0.0.0 and now everything works fine. But I want also to understand *why* this problem happened. My read is, that some other references are depending on EF in version 6.0.0.0 but I couldn't find out which ones.

I looked in the dependency-information of every installed NuGet package. The only one which refers to EntityFramework is MySQL.Data.Entity but **not** for the exact version 6.0.0.0, according to the info text he needs a version >= 6.0.0.0 so it should work fine with 6.1.3.0. Is there a way to let me see all assemblys depending on EntityFramework so that I can see which one depends on 6.0.0.0?

Comment: I think you are mixing product version and assembly versions together

Comment: On top of `rootturk`'s answer, if you already have a version of EF installed (sounds like you do), run `uninstall-package entityframework -force` first.

Answer (score 0):

First Manually install Entity-Framework-6.0 version on your project.

Open Console Package Manager in "Visual Studio" and execute this code

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0
```

And later Restart your solution and Right Click on Project select Manage Nuget Packages menu. Remove "Entity Framework 6.0.0" to all project and install Entity Framework last version on Nuget Packages Manager.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You may have two projects in your solution one using EF version 6.0.0 and the other project using 6.1.3.0.

If that is not the case consider updating all Nuget packages by right clicking on the project and Manage Nuget packages, then update all nuget packages.

Hope that helps.